# How to specify a lazy-loaded collection should be sorted in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

Is there a way to specify an order-by clause in my config XML to instruct nHibernate to lazy-load a collection property sorted by a particular property of the collection members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`order-by`](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-6-collection-mapping#6%282E%292%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Mapping_a_Collection) attribute in the collection mapping. The syntax is

```
order-by="column_name asc|desc"
```

Note that you specify the column name and not the property name.